# How to set TypeScript variable value as CSS property?

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I have an image (inside a material card) which changes every 30 seconds. I have the height of the image (as a TS variable) and I want to set it as the height of the loaded image. I tried the below approach but I think that the syntax is wrong. What is the right approach?

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-live',
templateUrl: 

 <mat-card [ngStyle]="{'min-height': '{{taille}}'}">
  <img  mat-card-image [src]="profileUrl | async " alt="Streaming de la culture" #img [ngStyle]="{'padding-top':'0px' }" (load)="dosomething(img)">
 </mat-card>

export class LiveComponent implements OnInit {

taille;

dosomething(img) { console.log(img.clientWidth, img.clientHeight);
                   this.taille = img.clientHeight;
                   console.log(this.taille);}
```

Comment: Remove `{{` and `}}`

Comment: better said remove `'{{` and `}}'` around `taille`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `{'min-height': '{{taille}}'}` part should in fact be `{'min-height': taille}`.
Angular [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/ajs-quick-reference#ngstyle) presents the below very similar example:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'color': colorPreference}">
```

From your sample code it seems that `taille` is initially `undefined` which you might want to take into account (initialize `taille` or use a `ngIf` or other approach).

Answer (score 3):

Using `[ngStyle]` -

```
<mat-card [ngStyle]="{'min-height': taille}">
```

Or you can use `[style.min-height] = "taille"` instead.

```
<mat-card [style.min-height] = "taille">
```

please go through [this](https://alligator.io/angular/style-binding-ngstyle-angular/) for more insights.